# Как проверить существует ли индекс?

Tags: java, mysql, index

Запускается некое приложение. Конектится к базе. Создаются таблицы(если не созданы ранее) и доходит очередь до создание индекса, но он мог уже быть создан ранее и из-за этого я получу исключение `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Duplicate key name 'tablename_index'` (Java). Как наиболее просто и правильно проверить, существует ли индекс и создать его, если он не был ранее создан.

Посоветовали [тему](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24541/120843)(я её ранее читал до создания вопроса здесь).

Там есть следующие:

You could just query for the existence of the index by name. For example, before you run

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON mytable(column);
```

You need to run

```
SELECT COUNT(1) IndexIsThere FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE table_schema=DATABASE() AND table_name='mytable' AND index_name='index_name';
```

Как объединить это в 1 запрос с обычным условием? Ибо создание таблиц в коде происходит через `addBatch`

```
private boolean deployTables() {
try {
    this.connection = getConnection();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    this.nextReconnect = -1L;
    Logging.severe("Error creating connection to database. (deploy tables)", ex);
}

try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
    statement.addBatch(CREATE_TABLE_KITS_SETTINGS);
    statement.addBatch(CREATE_TABLE_KITS_ITEMS);
    statement.addBatch(CREATE_TABLE_KITS_LOG);
    statement.addBatch(CREATE_TABLE_KITS_LOG_INDEX);
    statement.executeBatch();
    statement.close();
    return true;
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logging.severe("Error deploy tables tables in database.", ex);
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: В MySQL [только через задницу](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24541/120843).

Comment: Блин, читал я это, перед тем как спросить здесь. Неужели нет нормального способа? Даже в SQLite есть `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS`...

Comment: В том и беда, что даже SQLite полнее поддерживает стандарт SQL.

Comment: Это очень печально.

Comment: Перехватите исключение, убедитесь что оно касается именно дублирования и спите спокойно. Ну либо извращаться вроде `select @run:=case count(1)>0 then 'create index .....' else 'select 1 from dual where 0=1' end FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS ...; prepare XX from @run; execute XX` правда одним запросом это сложно назвать, не факт, что ваш драйвер проглотит. В общем я бы сам такое творить не стал. Еще как вариант сделать хранимую процедуру, которая примерно это же будет вытворять

Comment: Само по себе наличие у приложения прав ковыряться в структуре БД - уже нонсенс. А наличие при этом возможности того, что оператор не контролирует состояние дел (как можно не знать о существовании или не-существовании индекса?) - так и вовсе за гранью.

Comment: Да не в этом проблема. У нас на проекте есть много серверов(майнкрафт). На каждом из них должна быть база локальная, с которой плагин должен общаться для своего функционирования и хранения каких-либо данных. В данном случае мы решили так, раз уж для этого плагина база будет общая(глобальная), то таблицы и прочее создадим вручную и в плагин данный функционал добавлять не будем, ибо это не тот случай, когда нужна будет отдельная локальная база на каждом сервере.